# print JPEG to PDF, set paper size

Tags: vba, pdf, acrobat

Using VBA, for a given JPEG (or GIF or BMP), I want to print it to a PDF, and set the page size before printing.  I've looked at a couple of different ways to print, but no one of them seems to be able to do what I want:

- **Use the Acrobat SDK to call `AVDoc.Open()`, `AVDoc.GetPDDoc()`, and then `PDDoc.Save()`**: can't choose page size using this method
- **Declare WinAPI functions `SetDefaultPrinter` and `ShellExecute`, use `SetDefaultPrinter` to set printer to PDF print driver, then call `ShellExecute(1,"print",filepath,"",rootdirectory,1)`**: I haven't found a way to set page size with this method either

Page size can be set using the methods associated with an Office document object, e.g. `Worksheet.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaper11x17`, but this only sets page size for that object, not for the JPEG that I want to print.

Answer (score 1):

You could just import it into your Excel workbook and print it from there. Here's a rudimentary example:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pic As Picture

Set ws = ActiveSheet
ws.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperA4
'Can also specify margins, etc.

ws.Range("A1").Activate
Set pic = ws.Pictures.Insert("C:\mypic.jpg")   
'Set picture size.
With pic.ShapeRange
    .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    .Height = Application.CentimetersToPoints(20)
    .Width = Application.CentimetersToPoints(15)
    'Or you could match the size to the paper margins from above.
End With

ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="C:\mypic.pdf", OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Tested in Excel 2010.

Comment: @sigil Did this help at all?